# Auto-Populate List Form Fields Based On Lookup Selection In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have below requirement and kindly help me with solution.

Scenario: I have a list called Student and in that all details are there like student name, address , district, city and country with mobile number.
Now in the form i have filed like student name and its binded to student list which will fetch only student name.
Now i require your help – If i select a student name in that drop down then all other fields in the form like address, district , city and country should fill up automatically.

Could you please suggest me modified code please as i am beginner to this env.

Comment: Please, check this **[Auto Populate Field Values based on Lookup Selection In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest api to achieve this. Query your list on the student list dropdown change event and fetch the other details.

Sample code given below.

```
function autoFillFieldsFunction(itemId)
{
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DetailsToBeFetchedFromListName')/items("+itemId+")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("select[title='Savings']").val(data.d.Savings);
        },
        error : function (data) 
        {
            alert("Error: "+ data);
        }});
}
```